Latin cognate for Sanskrit "shoka" (sorrow)?
Is there a Latin cognate for the Sanskrit word "shoka"? In general, is there some resource that lists Indo-European cognates for any given language pair?

Oh, say, does the personal name Ashok mean ‘sorrowless’?

Yes. It's also a flower (Saraca asoca).

Looking at the Wiktionary entry for शोक, it seems to come from a root *ḱweyt-, which has reflexes listed for Indo-Iranian, Balto-Slavic, and Germanic, but not Italic.
Wiktionary isn't always the most reliable source, but it's hard to beat its completeness if you're looking for arbitrary pairs of languages. Most resources you'll find focus on a single language or family.

I don't know how reliable Wiktionary is in this particular instance -- how do you get Skt. k from *t-? And the page for the root शुच् derives it from another PIE root *ḱewk-.

Yeah, the association with *k̑u̯ei̯t- seems wrong – *k̑eu̯k- is a better fit both formally and semantically. LIV² has only Indo-Iranian reflexes of *k̑eu̯k- (and therefore a question mark before the root itself, indicating it may not be PIE at all).
